# Dji Mavic air 2 from sensor not working after drop in water

Tags: dji-mavic-air-2

Recently my drone crashed in a tree then felt down in water, and the front sensor did not work any more.

The error I was getting are: 180018 & 180019

I bought a new GPS module and new front sensor, replaced but the error still persist. Tried the DJI Assistant app, the sensors show green but there is no image.[image]

What else can I check or do to repair the drone?

[image]